# Call async method with callback from sync UI thread

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asynccallback

Im really stuck here... I have a XAML Page UI and want to call an async function everytime the user interacts with the UI.
I use SignalR for networking:

```
public static class ProtocolClient
{
    private static HubConnection hubConnection;
    private static IHubProxy protocolHubProxy;

    public static async void connect(string server)
    {
        hubConnection = new HubConnection(server);
        protocolHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ProtocolHub");
        protocolHubProxy.On<Body>("BodiesChanged", body =>
            //call a callback to return body
        );
        await hubConnection.Start(); //wait for connection
    }

    public static async void sendTouch(Touch touch)
    {
        Body body = await protocolHubProxy.Invoke<Body>("GetBodyForTouch", touch);
        //call a callback to return body
    }
}
```

UI:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    [...]
    private void Canvas_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        [...]
        switch (ptrPt.PointerDevice.PointerDeviceType)
        {
            case Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Mouse:
                if (ptrPt.Properties.IsLeftButtonPressed)
                {
                    //call sendTouch
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        [...]
    }
}
```

I need a callback which can modify the UI. How can I call connect and sendTouch out of the UI and pass them a callback?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a callback. Just add the code after the `await hubConnection.Start();` statement. Your method is 'cut in multiple methods' and will 'continue' after the await comes back. The `await` works like a blocking statement, but will not freeze the gui.

```
public static async void connect(string server)
{
    hubConnection = new HubConnection(server);
    protocolHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ProtocolHub");
    protocolHubProxy.On<Body>("BodiesChanged", body =>
        //call a callback to return body
    );
    await hubConnection.Start(); //wait for connection

    // add code here.
}
```

When handling commands async (from gui events), don't forget to disable controls to prevent executing the command more than ones.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I pass the body object from .On<Body> to the UI? These functions are in different classes.

Comment: Never worked with `SignalR`, but I assume that the `Start()` method is already returned when the `body` is called whenever a message arrives. So there is a misconception about where to handle the received messages. You don't need to 'move' the objects from the `On<Body>` event after the `await hubConnection.Start()`. Just handle the message there.

Comment: You are right. BUT class ProtocolClient does not and should not have anything to do with UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `async void` methods. If you don't need to return a value, use `async Task` - if you do, use `async Task<SomeType>`.

Then, when you need to call an async method (and by convention, these should be named like `ConnectAsync` and `SendTouchAsync`), `await` it:

```
await SendTouchAsync(...);
```

When the asynchronous workflow ends, your continuation will be marshalled back to the UI thread (because you `await`ed from within a synchronization context), and you can manipulate the UI easily.

`await` kind of appears to work when you use `async void`, but the problem is that the caller has no way of tracking the asynchronous workflow - as far as the caller is concerned, the method just ended right then and now, and the code in the caller continues as usual.

Make sure to mark `Canvas_PointerPressed` as `async` too - sadly, in this case, it *must* be `async void`. Make sure to never call the event handler directly - the UI thread can handle the callbacks correctly, your code can't. If you need the same logic from other methods, just separate it into a proper `async Task` method and `await` that from the event handler.

Comment: Thanks, but I still have no clue on how to get the body Object from On<Body> somehow to the caller class MainPage.

Comment: @pythonimus Just use the return value. Change the signature to `async Task<Body> SendTouchAsync(...)`, and just do `return body;` inside. The `await SendTouchAsync(...);` has your return value.

Comment: Thanks, but my question was how to get the body object from the [On function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn433683(v=vs.118).aspx) to the UI.

This part:
`protocolHubProxy.On<Body>("BodiesChanged", body => //call a callback to return body);`
How to create this Action callback and pass it to the connect function, so that the callback can modify UI elements?

Comment: @pythonimus Ah, okay. In that case, this is a 100% duplicate of the quite common "how do I modify the UI from another thread" question :)